# Match UIImage size with pdf size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf, swift3

In my app i am capturing screenshot of UIView and then i set that image on pdf, but i am getting different size for image and pdf frame. I am getting small image so while writing it on pdf it stretch and cutting down.

here is my code:

```
func drawOnPDF(path: String) {

    // Get existing Pdf reference
    let pdf = CGPDFDocument(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    // Get page count of pdf, so we can loop through pages and draw them accordingly
    let pageCount = pdf!.numberOfPages;

    // Write to file
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(path, CGRect.zero, nil)

    // Write to data
    //var data = NSMutableData()
    //UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil)

    for index in 1...pageCount {
        let page = pdf!.page(at: index)
        //            let pageFrame = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)
        let pageFrame = page?.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        page?.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)

        print(pageFrame)
        print(img.size)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame!, nil)

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // Draw existing page
        ctx!.saveGState();
        ctx!.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1);
        ctx!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -(pageFrame?.size.height)!);
        ctx!.drawPDFPage(page!);
        ctx!.restoreGState();

        // Draw image on top of page


            print(index)
            print(visibleIndexPath.row)
            if (index  == visibleIndexPath.row + 1)
            {


                img.draw(in: pageFrame!)



        }


    }


    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

}
```

Now here I am getting image size(319.0, 339.0)
while pdf page frame size is (0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0)

So how can I set both same in iOS swift.

Answer (score 0):

after

```
ctx!.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1); 

context.scaleBy(x: 319.0/612.0, y: 339.0/792.0))
```

scale your content according  to image size and it would fit.

.mediaBox is a enum that represent a fixed size

you can get image size using--->(below)

yourimg.size.width and  yourimg.size.height

Comment: what is context? where to define it? its showing me that use of unresolve identifier context

Comment: context is ctx in your case sorry for my fault